# How do I proxy AJAX requests with Rack Middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, reverse-proxy

I'm developing a Rails application that uses an API backend for AJAX requests written with Sinatra.

The API runs separately from Rails:

**Rails:** `localhost:3000`
**API:**   `localhost:9393`

In production, we'll be proxying requests to the API with nginx.

The problem is that we don't have nginx in development mode, we're using thin. So I need some sort of Rack middleware that I can add in development mode to proxy the requests for me.

Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question and giving me an idea! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps Rack::Proxy:

http://coderack.org/users/cwninja/middlewares/18-rackproxy

```
use Rack::Proxy do |req|
  if req.path =~ %r{identify api request with regex here}
    URI.parse("http://localhost:9393/#{req.fullpath}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would this go? In `config.ru`? In an initializer?